# Use Buttons to trigger filter function on react-table in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-table

I don't know how to word this.  I am learning React and I have data loaded into React-Table via fetch.  I tried using React-Table and just custom plain divs and tables.

I want to create a touch buttons of the alphabet from A, B, C, D ... Z.  Those buttons should call the filter for the letter that is in the button.  So, for example the buttons are the following.

```
// In Directory.js
class FilterButtons extends React.Component {

alphaFilter(e) {
  console.log(e.target.id);
  // somehow filter the react table
}

render() {

 return (
    <div>
       <button onClick={this.alphaFilter} id="A" className="letter">A</button>
       <button onClick={this.alphaFilter} id="B" className="letter">B</button>
       <button onClick={this.alphaFilter} id="C" className="letter">C</button>
    </div>
  );
 }
}

const BottomMenu = props => (
  <div className="btm-menu">
  <div className="toprow">
  <div className="filter-keys">
    <FilterButtons />
  </div>
</div>
</div>
);
```

// I have a class Directory extends Component that has the BottomMenu in it

// I also have a DataGrid.js with the React Table in there

```
class DataGrid extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      data: [],
    };
  }

  componentWillMount() {

    fetch('http://localhost:3000/rooms.json').then((results) => results.json()).then((data) => {
        console.log(data.room);

        this.setState({
          data: data.room
        })
      })
  }

  render() {
    const { data } = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
        <ReactTable
          data={data}
          filterable
          defaultFilterMethod={(filter, row) =>
            String(row[filter.id]) === filter.value}
          columns={[
                {
                  Header: "Name",
                  accessor: "dName",
                  filterMethod: (filter, row) =>
                    row[filter.id].startsWith(filter.value)
                },
                {
                  Header: "Department",
                  accessor: "dDept"
                },
                {
                  Header: "Room",
                  accessor: "dRoom"
                },
                {
                  Header: "Map",
                  accessor: "dRoom",
                  id: "over",
                }

              ]
            }

          defaultPageSize={14}
          className="-striped -highlight"
        />
        <br />

      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default DataGrid;
```

At this point I am unsure what to do to get the button click of one of the A, B, C letters to filter the React Table.  I do not want the Input field option that is always used because I want only buttons as the user will not have a keyboard, only touch.

Basically, React Table or just any table that can be filtered by clicking buttons with a letter that gets passed back to the filter.  If I was using JQuery I would use a button click and then filter that way.  I still haven't learned all the ins and outs of React and how to get this done.  I also want to use external buttons to sort but that should be easier, hopefully.

Thanks.
Sorry if all of this doesn't make sense, I am just trying to lay it out.  Again, no keyboard, only touch on a touch screen so the input field isn't going to work for me.

Comment: do you still have the issue?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For React-Table filter to be controlled externally by buttons, you should take a look at the [Controlled Table](https://react-table.js.org/#/story/controlled-component) example. Then the table component becomes a **[controlled component.](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#controlled-components)**

There, you can set the state of the table filter externally and use both of the props:

```
<ReactTable  ...(your other props)
        filtered={this.state.filtered}
        onFilteredChange={filtered => this.setState({ filtered })}
 />
```

The `filtered` prop will monitor change in the state. So whenever you update its value through your letter buttons via e.g.

```
this.setState({filtered: { id: "dName", value: "A"}})
```

the table's filter will get updated. Also, onFilteredChange should work the other direction, namely the embedded filtering of the react-table can update the local state. So that you can monitor it and use its value within your DataGrid component.

One other option could be to avoid using local states and implement it in redux, though. Because states hanging around components are eventually becoming source of errors and increasing complexity of debugging.

UPDATE -- As per the question owner's comment for more details:

In order to use FilterButtons and DataGrid together, you can define a container component that encapsulates both FilterButtons and DataGrid. 
The container component keeps the shared state, and the filtering function operates on the state function. But data will still reside within the datagrid.

```
class DataGridWithFilter extends React.Component {

// you need constructor() for binding alphaFilter to this. 
// otherwise it cannot call this.setState
constructor(props) {
   super(props);
   this.alphaFilter = this.alphaFilter.bind(this);
}

// personally i do not use ids for passing data. 
// therefore introduced the l parameter for the letter
alphaFilter(e,l) {
  console.log(e.target.id);
  this.setState({filtered: { id: "dName", value: l}});
}

 render(){
   return <div>
      <DataGrid filtered={this.state.filtered} 
                filterFunc={this.alphaFilter}
      </DataGrid>
      <BottomMenu filtered={this.state.filtered}
                  filterFunc={this.alphaFilter} />
   </div>
 }
}
```

Also this above thing requires the use of prop `filterFunc` from within BottomMenu and FilterButtons components.

```
class FilterButtons extends React.Component {
render() {
 const {props} =  this;
 return (
    <div>
       <button onClick={(e) => props.filterFunc(e, "A")} id="A" className="letter">A</button>
       <button onClick={(e) => props.filterFunc(e, "B")} id="B" className="letter">B</button>
       <button onClick={(e) => props.filterFunc(e, "C")} id="C" className="letter">C</button>
    </div>
  );
 }
}

const BottomMenu = props => (
  <div className="btm-menu">
  <div className="toprow">
  <div className="filter-keys">
    <FilterButtons filterFunc = {props.filterFunc} />
  </div>
</div>
</div>
); 



class DataGrid extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      data: [],
    };
  }

  componentWillMount() {

    fetch('http://localhost:3000/rooms.json').then((results) => results.json()).then((data) => {
        console.log(data.room);

        this.setState({
          data: data.room
        })
      })
  }

  render() {
    const { data } = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
        <ReactTable
          data={data}
          filterable
          defaultFilterMethod={(filter, row) =>
            String(row[filter.id]) === filter.value}
          columns={[
                {
                  Header: "Name",
                  accessor: "dName",
                  filterMethod: (filter, row) =>
                    row[filter.id].startsWith(filter.value)
                },
                {
                  Header: "Department",
                  accessor: "dDept"
                },
                {
                  Header: "Room",
                  accessor: "dRoom"
                },
                {
                  Header: "Map",
                  accessor: "dRoom",
                  id: "over",
                }

              ]
            }

          defaultPageSize={14}
          className="-striped -highlight"
          filtered = {this.props.filtered}
          onFilteredChange = {filtered => this.props.filterFunc({filtered})}
        />
        <br />
       </div>
    );
  }
}
```

I have not checked against typo etc but this should work.

Comment: Thanks.  I am looking into it and I will report back.

Comment: Thanks.  I tried to implement this and onclick the filtered did not seem to update the react-table.  I might try to get his in a codepen or something.  Caan you explain the redux option?  How that would work?  Thanks.

Comment: Yes I am happy to explain redux but it should be topic of another question I have reviewed your code a bit more, you should not make any async calls in componentWillMount because it may leave your table uninitialized, because the state change may go undetected. Have you looked at the React Table controlled component example? It has a codepen that you can play with, too.

Comment: @donlaur I have checked the code on codepen. Here you can find a working example. Enjoy. Please don't forget to accept it as an answer. https://codesandbox.io/s/wy574pkrl8

Comment: When I try to move over the codepen example when I click the A,B,C buttons I get the error of TypeError: props.filterFunc is not a function.

Comment: @donlaur I can't reproduce that on my browser. Don't forget this line in the render function of the button `const {props} = this;`. Or use `this.props.filterFunc` instead.

Comment: is there a definition of filterFunc anywhere?  The error I get is that it is not a function.

Comment: Yep, the `<DataGrid filterFunc={this.alphaFilter} ... />` defines it. It should be there in the sandbox, as a method within `DataGridWithFilter` component.

Comment: While this works with the 2 sample rows, how to make it work with the imported JSON file that was read in the componentDidMount?

Comment: @donlaur you can put the `fetch` request in the `componentDidMount` method of the `DataGridWithFilter` component, and remove the sample lines in its constructor. Please see the commented part in the `componentDidMount`.

Answer (score 2):

In React, you can update components when state changes. The only way to trigger is to use this.setState()

So I would change my state object something like this:

```
state = {
  date: [],
  filter: ""
};
```

so here is the new file:

```
// In Directory.js
class FilterButtons extends React.Component {

alphaFilter = (word) => {
  this.setState({
    filter: word
  });
};

render() {

 return (
    <div>
       <button onClick={() => this.alphaFilter("A")} id="A" className="letter">A</button>
       <button onClick={() => this.alphaFilter("B")} id="B" className="letter">B</button>
       <button onClick={() => this.alphaFilter("C")} id="C" className="letter">C</button>
    </div>
  );
 }
}

const BottomMenu = props => (
  <div className="btm-menu">
  <div className="toprow">
  <div className="filter-keys">
    <FilterButtons />
  </div>
</div>
</div>
);
```

right after you call `alphaFilter()` your component will update. And when you put your filter function in it it's going display as expected. So I would choose the `.map()` function of array. You can either use `filter()` or return after comparing data in `map()`

Comment: I changed the code and word does show the button is clicked.  How do I update the filterable part or filterMethod in the render of my DataGrid.js file as it is still attached to the input field and not using the buttons?  Thanks, somewhat lost, pretty lost here.

Answer (score 0):

For react-table 7 you can listen for input changes outside and call `setFilter`:

```
useEffect(() => {
  // This will now use our custom filter for age
  setFilter("age", ageOutside);
}, [ageOutside]);
```

See https://codesandbox.io/s/react-table-filter-outside-table-bor4f?file=/src/App.js